# Why my button is not showing the text?

Tags: c#, button, text

I have a class CircularButton that extends of Button and a button, which is not showing the text, with or without a BackColor. Can't figure out what is happening:

```
public class CircularButton : Button {


    public CircularButton(Color c, String text){
        Font = new Font("Arial", 20f, FontStyle.Bold);
        BackColor = c;
        Text = text;
    }
    public Action<PaintEventArgs> DoPaint { get; set; }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
      if (DoPaint != null) { DoPaint(e); }
    }
}

//make a new circular button, the text is just a letter.
CircularButton btn = new CircularButton(Color.Red,"A");
    btn.Bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
    btn.Enabled = false;                        
    btn.DoPaint = delegate(PaintEventArgs p){
        Graphics graphics = p.Graphics;
        SolidBrush brush1 = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ButtonFace);
        graphics.FillRectangle(brush1, 0, 0, btn.Width, btn.Height);
        SolidBrush brush2 = new SolidBrush(btn.BackColor);
        graphics.FillEllipse(brush2, 0, 0, btn.Width, btn.Height);
};
```

Comment: Your paint doesnt write any text..

Comment: I'm guessing this is winforms, why not just use the Region property of a standard button to clip it to a circle?

Comment: @ZoharPeled  Because I come from Java, I getting use to the .net libraries, still don't know most of them.

Comment: @BugFinder Can you explain more pls?

Comment: You fill a rectangle, and fill an ellipse you dont write any text.. what else can I say.. there is no text writing going on..

Comment: You could exaplain the difference between setting a text ( btn.Text ) and drawing a text, but np, solved.

Comment: Why use a delegate?  It should be enough to put your drawing code directly inside the `OnPaint` override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `OnPaint` which would draw the text in the base button. So you have to write the text yourself:

```
graphics.DrawString(btn.Text, btn.Font, new SolidBrush(btn.ForeColor), x, y);
```